# How to query an Entity from a Many-to-Many realtionship dependendt on two ore more conditions in Ktor with the Kotlin Exposed Framework?

Tags: sql, postgresql, kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I have 3 entities:

| User |
| --- |
| id: Int |
| name: String |

| Room |
| --- |
| id: Int |
| name: String |

| RoomUser |
| --- |
| id: Int |
| room_id: Int (Reference on Room.id) |
| user_id: Int (Reference on User.id) |

Now lets say we have 2 rooms and 3 users:

Rooms:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Room1 |
| 2 | Room2 |

Users:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | User3 |
| 7 | User7 |
| 9 | User9 |

RoomUsers:

| id | room_id | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 7 |
| 3 | 2 | 7 |
| 4 | 2 | 9 |

As you can see, **User3** and **User7** are in the room **Room1** and **User7** and **User9** are in the room **Room2**.

In my use case I have given for example 2 users. Now I want to get the room, in which these both Users are.

In this case, when I have given the users **User3** and **User7** I want to get the room **Room1** or when I have given the users **User7** and **User9** I want to get the room **Room2**.

How can I write an query with the Kotlin Exposed Framework to get this specific room?

Comment: You want to fetch the room where both users exists?

Comment: Exactly. I want tonfetch the room where both unseres exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL notation it should be like:

```sql
SELECT room_id
FROM RoomUsers
where user_id in (3,7)
GROUP BY room_id
HAVING count(*) = 2
```

In Exposed:

```kotlin
RoomUsers
  .slice(RoomUsers.roomId)
  .select{
     RoomUsers.userId inList listOf(User3.id, User7.id)
  }
  .groupBy(RoomUsers.roomId)
  .having {
    RoomUsers.userId.count() eq 2
  }.map {
    it[RoomUsers.roomId]
  }
```